# Prime splitting in the division field of an elliptic curve

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, elliptic-curves, galois-theory, galois-representations

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve with good reduction at two distinct primes $p, \ell$. Suppose the mod $\ell$ Galois representation associated to $E$ is surjective. Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(E[\ell])$ be the field cut out by the representation. Then $G=\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q}) \simeq \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_\ell)$.

In a 2002 paper by Duke and Tóth ([MR1969646](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=1969646)), a recipe is given for constructing a matrix $\sigma_p$ representing the conjugacy class of Frobenius at $p$ inside $G$. Since $p$ is unramified in $K/\mathbb{Q}$, we should be able to determine the decomposition behavior of $p$ in $K$ using this matrix in two ways. In particular, let $g$ denote the number of distinct primes above $p$ in $K$.

1. Let $d$ be the multiplicative order of $\sigma_p$. Then $d$ corresponds to the inertial degree of every prime above $p$, so $g=\frac{|G|}{d}$.
2. Let $\mathcal{C} \subset G$ denote the conjugacy class of $\sigma_p$ in $G$. Since the primes above $p$ are all conjugate, we have $g=|\mathcal{C}$|.

However, in practice one can write down the matrix $\sigma_p$ and directly compute (e.g. using Sage) all of the quantities above, and methods (1) and (2) often yield different values. Here is a concrete example:

Let $E$ be the elliptic curve with Cremona label [43a1](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/43/a/1). Then $E$ has surjective mod 5 Galois representation and good (supersingular) reduction at $p=2$ (with $a_p(E)=-2)$. The recipe of Duke-Toth yields the matrix
$$\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1\end{matrix}\right).$$
Considered as an element of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_5)$, this matrix has multiplicative order $d=4$ and lives in a conjugacy class of cardinality $|\mathcal{C}|=30$. The cardinality of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_5)$ is $480$. But clearly 480/4=120, not 30.

At first I thought something might be going wrong since $p=2$, $E$ is supersingular at $2$, and $a_p(E) \neq 0$. But it's easy enough to find plenty of other examples where $p, \ell$ are both larger, and where $E$ has good ordinary reduction.

What explains this discrepancy?

Comment: I think your number theory is wrong. There is no correspondence between elements in $\mathcal{C}$ to primes above $p$, for example take $K/\mathbb{Q}$ abelian and any prime $p$ which does stay prime in $K$, then $|\mathcal{C}|=1$ and $g>1$.

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Comment: @re'emwaxman : Thanks -- I figured my mistake had to be at that step. I'm still a bit confused about it, but your extreme example of an abelian extension is extremely helpful for convincing me that this is where I've goofed.

Comment: Also your example doesn't have trace equal to $a_p=-2$.

Comment: The thing needed to be understood is that if $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{p}'$ are two primes above $p$ then $\text{Frob}_{\mathfrak{p}}$ and $\text{Frob}_{\mathfrak{p}'}$ are conjugate in $G$ but might be the same even if the primes are distinct.

Comment: @re'emwaxman Yes, that's exactly the point I was somehow missing, but your comment made my false belief clear to me. Thanks so much again!

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich You're right, I accidentally wrote down the Duke-Toth matrix for when a_p=2 rather than -2, but it doesn't affect the rest of my question -- in particular, it was not the source of my error. But thanks for catching that.